# object is not iterable with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, iteration

I keep getting Type errors on list not being callable, although the I receive the print of output on my terminal... what is calling the list if we are on a loop?

```
def work(page):  
    #-------------------------
    #make obj of page and do something
    grabthis = Some_class1(page)
    f = Someclass_2(grabthis,page)
    output = f.extract()
    print(output)
            
pages='PDFPAGES'            
            
#set page
save = []
for page in pages:
    go = work(page) 
    start = multiprocessing.Process(target=go)
    start.start()
    save.append(start)
    if go == 'norun':
        continue
    
for items in save:
    start.join()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

what is the correct way to iterate a bunch of files through multiprocessing or threading?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Done and it is meant to be python2.7

Comment: You assign the result of a call to `work(page)` to "go". This isn't a valid target. Instead remove this and start process with `start = multiprocessing.Process(target=work, args=(page,))`. By the way: If you want to run this on Windows, additional preparations are necessary.

Comment: `go = work(page)` The work() function has no `return` statement, therefore it returns `None`.  Therefore `go` is None.  Did you intend this?

Comment: Your title is incorrect; callability and iterability are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

See the comment posted by Michael Butscher as it is most likely that your intention is to have function `work` process pages either concurrently (multithreading) or in parallel (multiprocessing). The difference is that with multithreading each thread must acquire the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) before it can run Python code so no two threads will ever be executing Python code at the same time (in parallel). This is not too much of an issue if `work` is (1) mostly I/O bound and releases the GIL when it is waiting for I/O (or a network request) to complete so that most of the time it is just waiting or (2) you are executing C/C++ code (which some library modules use for their implementation) that releases the GIL. Otherwise you have CPU-intensive processing to do in which case multiprocessing is the way to go. However, multiprocessing has has additional overhead that serial processing does not, i.e. the creation of processes and moving data across processes (different address spaces). So unless `work` is significantly CPU-intensive, a multiprocessing solution will run more slowly than a serial one.

Let's assume `work` is such that multiprocessing is the correct approach. Assuming that in addition to its high CPU requirements there is also a fair amount of waiting involved. Then it might be advantageous to create more processes than you have CPU cores since the processes will from time to time go in a wait state and allow other processes to run. But if there is little or no I/O processing involved, you gain nothing by creating more processes than you have CPU cores. Let's assume the latter and let `N` be the number of CPU cores you have and `M` is the number of pages that you have to process. If `M` is <= `N`, then you could create a process for each page as you are doing since you do not seem to be returning a value back from `work` (but using multiprocessing pool is probably simpler):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def work(page):  
    #-------------------------
    #make obj of page and do something
    grabthis = Some_class1(page)
    f = Someclass_2(grabthis,page)
    output = f.extract()
    print(output)
            
pages='PDFPAGES'            

# Required for Windows or any platform that uses the *spawn* method to
# create new processes:
if __name__ == '__main__':            
    processes = []
    for page in pages:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=go, args=(page,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

But if `M` > `P`, i.e. you have more pages to process than CPU cores you have, or if `work` needs to return a result back to the main process, I would then use a multiprocessing pool, which is also suitable even if `M` < `P`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def work(page):  
    #-------------------------
    #make obj of page and do something
    grabthis = Some_class1(page)
    f = Someclass_2(grabthis,page)
    output = f.extract()
    print(output)
            
pages='PDFPAGES'            

# Required for Windows or any platform that uses the *spawn* method to
# create new processes:
if __name__ == '__main__':            
    # This will create a pool whose size is never more than the number of
    # CPU cores you have or the number of pages you have to process:
    pool_size = min(cpu_count(), len(pages))
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(go, pages) # or results = pool.map(go, pages) if `work` returns something
    # Cleanup pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

But if `work` is mostly I/O bound, then use a multithreading pool. The pool size can be quite large, but you should still keep it to a reasonable size (200?):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def work(page):  
    #-------------------------
    #make obj of page and do something
    grabthis = Some_class1(page)
    f = Someclass_2(grabthis,page)
    output = f.extract()
    print(output)

pages='PDFPAGES'            

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    # This will create a pool whose size is never more than 200 or
    # the number of pages you have to process:
    pool_size = min(200, len(pages))
    pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)
    pool.map(go, pages) # or results = pool.map(go, pages) if `work` returns something
    # Cleanup pool:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**Note**

The above are just generalizations. But if your `work` function is *iterating files* as you say, then multithreading *might* be the best approach. But there is a maximum data rate your disk has so creating more threads will not help performance. Moreover, if you don't have a solid state drive, then the extra head movement caused by reading multiple files concurrently can hurt performance and two threads may run more slowly than the serial approach. You could start with a pool size of 2 and see if it improves performance and then slowly increasing the pool size. The only problem is that your operating system probably caches disk data so that when you rerun the code with a different pool size, it will run faster just due to the caching. You either need to find a way of purging the disk cache between runs or re-booting between runs.